# Centering tabs with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem centering my tabs menu on my website. I've tried several of the solutions that have previously been published here on other questions, but since they haven't worked for me, I hope you can help me also.

```css
/*----- Tab Links -----*/


/* Clearfix */

.tab-links:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}

.tab-links {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin: auto 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.tab-links li {
  margin: auto 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  /*float:left;*/
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

.tab-links a {
  padding: 9px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #808080;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab-links a:hover {
  color: #2ebb98;
}

li.active a,
li.active a:hover {
  color: #2ebb98;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2ebb98;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab-links">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">Tab two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Tab three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab4">Tab four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab5">Tab five</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab6">Tab six</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab7">Tab seven</a></li>
</ul>
```

The text for each tab is centered nicely, but the actual menu alone is not centered. Does anyone have any idea how to get it centered?

Comment: The menu is centered because you defined its width at 100%. If you want to center the `li` inside of the `ul` then use Jonathan's solution

Answer (score 1):

Since your `<li>`s are `inline-block`, you can add a `padding-left:0;` (by default, browsers add a padding to `ul`) and `text-align:center;` to you `<ul>`.

```css
/*----- Tab Links -----*/
/* Clearfix */
.tab-links:after {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  content:'';
}

.tab-links {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin: auto 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.tab-links li {
  margin: auto 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  /*float:left;*/
  display: inline-block;
  list-style:none;
}

.tab-links a {
  padding:9px 10px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:600;
  color:#808080;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab-links a:hover {
  color:#2ebb98;
}

li.active a, li.active a:hover {
  color:#2ebb98;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2ebb98;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab-links">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">Tab two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Tab three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab4">Tab four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab5">Tab five</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab6">Tab six</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab7">Tab seven</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the  element flex is a good way to justify contents.

```
.tab-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your content inside the `.tab-links` are `inline-block`.

Just add `text-align: center;` to the `.tab-links`.

That's it.

```
.tab-links {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**DEMO**

```css
 /*----- Tab Links -----*/


    /* Clearfix */
    .tab-links:after {
      display: block;
      clear: both;
      content: '';
    }

    .tab-links {
      width: 100%;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
      margin: auto 0;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      
      /* UPDATED CODE */
      
      text-align: center;
    }

    .tab-links li {
      margin: auto 0;
      margin-left: 2px;
      /*float:left;*/
      display: inline-block;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .tab-links a {
      padding: 9px 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #808080;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .tab-links a:hover {
      color: #2ebb98;
    }

    li.active a,
    li.active a:hover {
      color: #2ebb98;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #2ebb98;
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="tab-links">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2">Tab two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab3">Tab three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab4">Tab four</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab5">Tab five</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab6">Tab six</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab7">Tab seven</a></li>
    </ul>
```